# System Close Button surfaces in custom window chrome when ResizeMode is set to NoResize

Tags: wpf, winapi, window-chrome

I have implemented a custom window chrome using the WPF Shell Integration Library (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell).

The Chrome works until I set the ReSizeMode to NoResize. Then if hover over the Close Button, I notice that underlying System Close Button is displayed under the custom chrome close button.[image: Custom Chrome Button partially hides System Close Button]

The Expected behaviour is that the underlying Close Button should never show up. If I move the window or select another window on my desktop and come back to this one, I notice that System Close Button is again hidden.
So the probably is essentially when (1) the application first startup and (2) when ResizeMode = NoResize.

My first suspicion is how we handle the WM.NCHITTEST in the Custom Chrome. If I modify this function to return HTCLient then this problem is solved. However, I lose the ability to drag and drop as well as right click on the Caption Bar.

Here is the code for the handler of WM.NCHITTEST message from WindowsChromeWorker Class.

```
    private IntPtr _HandleNCHitTest( WM uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, out bool handled ) {
        IntPtr lRet = IntPtr.Zero;
        handled = false;

        // Give DWM a chance at this first.
        if ( Utility.IsOSVistaOrNewer && _chromeInfo.GlassFrameThickness != default( Thickness ) && _isGlassEnabled ) {
            // If we're on Vista, give the DWM a chance to handle the message first.
            handled = NativeMethods.DwmDefWindowProc( _hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, out lRet );
        }


        // Handle letting the system know if we consider the mouse to be in our effective non-client area.
        // If DWM already handled this by way of DwmDefWindowProc, then respect their call.
        if ( IntPtr.Zero == lRet ) {
            var mousePosScreen = new Point( Utility.GET_X_LPARAM( lParam ), Utility.GET_Y_LPARAM( lParam ) );
            Rect windowPosition = _GetWindowRect();

            HT ht = _HitTestNca(
                DpiHelper.DeviceRectToLogical( windowPosition ),
                DpiHelper.DevicePixelsToLogical( mousePosScreen ) );

            // Don't blindly respect HTCAPTION.
            // We want UIElements in the caption area to be actionable so run through a hittest first.
            if ( ht != HT.CLIENT) {
                Point mousePosWindow = mousePosScreen;
                mousePosWindow.Offset( -windowPosition.X, -windowPosition.Y );
                mousePosWindow = DpiHelper.DevicePixelsToLogical( mousePosWindow );
                IInputElement inputElement = _window.InputHitTest( mousePosWindow );
                if ( inputElement != null && WindowChrome.GetIsHitTestVisibleInChrome( inputElement ) ) {
                    ht = HT.CLIENT;
                }
            }
            //handled = false;
            handled = true;
            lRet = new IntPtr((int)ht);
        }
        return lRet;
    }

    private static readonly HT[,] _HitTestBorders = new[,]
    {
        { HT.TOPLEFT,    HT.TOP,     HT.TOPRIGHT    },
        { HT.LEFT,       HT.CLIENT,  HT.RIGHT       },
        { HT.BOTTOMLEFT, HT.BOTTOM,  HT.BOTTOMRIGHT },
    };

    private HT _HitTestNca( Rect windowPosition, Point mousePosition ) {
        // Determine if hit test is for resizing, default middle (1,1).
        int uRow = 1;
        int uCol = 1;
        bool onResizeBorder = false;

        //if (_window.ResizeMode == ResizeMode.NoResize)
          //  _chromeInfo.ResizeBorderThickness = new Thickness(0);

        // Determine if the point is at the top or bottom of the window.
        if ( mousePosition.Y >= windowPosition.Top && mousePosition.Y < windowPosition.Top + _chromeInfo.ResizeBorderThickness.Top + _chromeInfo.CaptionHeight ) {
            onResizeBorder = ( mousePosition.Y < ( windowPosition.Top + _chromeInfo.ResizeBorderThickness.Top ) );
            uRow = 0; // top (caption or resize border)
        } else if ( mousePosition.Y < windowPosition.Bottom && mousePosition.Y >= windowPosition.Bottom - (int)_chromeInfo.ResizeBorderThickness.Bottom ) {
            uRow = 2; // bottom
        }

        // Determine if the point is at the left or right of the window.
        if ( mousePosition.X >= windowPosition.Left && mousePosition.X < windowPosition.Left + (int)_chromeInfo.ResizeBorderThickness.Left ) {
            uCol = 0; // left side
        } else if ( mousePosition.X < windowPosition.Right && mousePosition.X >= windowPosition.Right - _chromeInfo.ResizeBorderThickness.Right ) {
            uCol = 2; // right side
        }

        // If the cursor is in one of the top edges by the caption bar, but below the top resize border,
        // then resize left-right rather than diagonally.
        if ( uRow == 0 && uCol != 1 && !onResizeBorder ) {
            uRow = 1;
        }

        HT ht = _HitTestBorders[uRow, uCol];

        if ( ht == HT.TOP && !onResizeBorder) {
            ht = HT.CAPTION;
        }

        return ht;
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Many Thanks,
Arjun

Answer (score 3):

All rite..I did figure this problem out.

First of all my initial suspicions were wrong. The handling of the WM.NCHITTEST message **wasnt** incorrect. It was really a question of Window Styles.

The best solution was to hide the System Close button and let the Chrome Close button do its work instead. But the solution that you find on the net i.e toggle SYSMENU bit flag in the Window styles http://winsharp93.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/wpf-hide-the-window-buttons-minimize-restore-and-close-and-the-icon-of-a-window/ did not work in my case.

The Close Button is hidden but inspite of the ResizeMode set to NoResize, I noticed that both the Resize Cursor and Resize Menu { Max\Min\Restore} were enabled.

After a few hours of trial and errors, I came up with this piece of code :

```
    //This property descriptor is used to hook-onto the resizemode change notification

      private void Window_Loaded( object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
      // When the default handling of ResizeMode = NoResize causes problems - this is why custom handling is required.
    System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor _resizeModePropertyDescriptor;

     _resizeModePropertyDescriptor = System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Window.ResizeModeProperty,
            typeof(Window));
        _resizeModePropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(this._window, new EventHandler(this._Window_ResizeModePropertyChanged));
      }

    /// <summary>
    /// This property change handler only reacts when the ReSizeMode is set to NoResize.
    /// In the default window style when Resize = NoResize, causes the underlying system close button to show up under the Chrome Close Button.
    /// This is a fix to handle that problem. [ Refer to defect #5134 for further details.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">ChromeWorker object</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event Args - Not really used</param>
    private void _Window_ResizeModePropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_window.ResizeMode == ResizeMode.NoResize)
        {
            //Got these styles merely by trial and error.
            _ModifyStyle(
                WS.SYSMENU | WS.DLGFRAME | WS.BORDER | WS.CLIPCHILDREN | WS.CLIPSIBLINGS,  //Styles to Remove
                WS.POPUPWINDOW);                                                            //Style to Add
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Add and remove a native WindowStyle from the HWND.</summary>
    /// <param name="removeStyle">The styles to be removed.  These can be bitwise combined.</param>
    /// <param name="addStyle">The styles to be added.  These can be bitwise combined.</param>
    /// <returns>Whether the styles of the HWND were modified as a result of this call.</returns>
    private bool _ModifyStyle( WS removeStyle, WS addStyle ) {
        Assert.IsNotDefault( _hwnd );
        var dwStyle = (WS)NativeMethods.GetWindowLongPtr( _hwnd, GWL.STYLE ).ToInt32();
        var dwNewStyle = ( dwStyle & ~removeStyle ) | addStyle;
        if ( dwStyle == dwNewStyle ) {
            return false;
        }

        NativeMethods.SetWindowLongPtr( _hwnd, GWL.STYLE, new IntPtr( (int)dwNewStyle ) );
        return true;
    }
```

You can also use the SourceInitialized event for the wireup but I havent really tested that.
Thats it! That captures an intense week of exploration of Window Chromes!

I have to admit I am a bit intrigued - woking on WPF for so long didnt make me realise that there is a whole world of win32 out there which is much more powerful( and frustrating as well!)